# Fixing the width of a subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to fix the width of one of the subplots to a fixed value. The issue comes from the fact that I'm combining ax.imshow() and ax.plot in the same column of plots and I'd like my plots to have the same width so that they line up on both sides, since they should share the x axis. to complicate things, the ax.imshow() also has a colorbar, which I introduced with ax.figure.colorbar() and that needs to be ignored when talking about the width of the plot. So far the only way I managed to make it work is by inserting values for ax.set_aspect() manually, but it takes a long time to get it right by trial and error.

I won't bore you with the details, especially because the code is a bit too long, but I'll include it here for completeness, hoping that it won't cause too much confusion. You won't be able to run it yourself unfortunately, since I'm only including the plotting part of the code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
df_spec = pd.read_csv(path + spec_name, header=spec_header, skipfooter=3)
df_spec['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df_spec['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

dates_list = df_spec['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'].to_list()
x_lims_ = [dates_list[0].timestamp(), dates_list[-1].timestamp()]
x_lims = list(map(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp, x_lims_))
x_lims = mdates.date2num(x_lims)

y_lims0 = np.linspace(1075, 13825, 100)
y_lims1 = np.linspace(20, 1040, 100)
y_lims2 = np.linspace(4, 245, 100)

@plt.FuncFormatter
def fake_log(x, pos):
    'The two args are the value and tick position'
    return round(10**x) #r'$10^{%.2f}$' % (x)

df_spec = df_spec.set_index('EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ')
df_spec = df_spec[df_spec.columns[::-1]].T

df_spec0 = df_spec.iloc[353:-1, :]
df_spec1 = df_spec.iloc[95:353, :]
df_spec2 = df_spec.iloc[0:95, :]

date_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
locator = mdates.HourLocator([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(15,20))

for a in ax:
    a.set_anchor('W')

for a in ax:
    a.patch.set_facecolor('black')

im = ax[0].imshow(df_spec0, norm=colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm.inferno, extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[1],  np.log10(y_lims0[0]), np.log10(y_lims0[-1])], aspect='auto')


ax[0].figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].xaxis.set(major_formatter=date_format, major_locator=locator)
ax[0].tick_params(bottom = False)
ax[0].set_xticks([])
ax[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(fake_log)
ax[0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5)) 
ax[0].set_yticks(np.log10(np.array([2000, 5000, 10000])))


im = ax[1].imshow(df_spec1, norm=colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm.inferno, extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[1],  np.log10(y_lims1[0]), np.log10(y_lims1[-1])], aspect='auto')


ax[1].figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].xaxis.set(major_formatter=date_format, major_locator=locator)
ax[1].tick_params(bottom = False)
ax[1].set_xticks([])
ax[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(fake_log)
ax[1].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5)) 
ax[1].set_yticks(np.log10(np.array([20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000])))


im = ax[2].imshow(df_spec2, norm=colors.LogNorm(), cmap=cm.inferno, extent = [x_lims[0], x_lims[1],  np.log10(y_lims2[0]), np.log10(y_lims2[-1])], aspect='auto')


ax[2].figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax[2])
ax[2].xaxis.set(major_formatter=date_format, major_locator=locator)
ax[2].tick_params(bottom = False)
ax[2].set_xticks([])
ax[2].yaxis.set_major_formatter(fake_log)
ax[2].yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5)) 
ax[2].set_yticks(np.log10(np.array([10, 20, 50, 100, 200])))

#second set of images

df1 = pd.read_csv(path + f1_name, header=f1_header, skipfooter=3)
df1['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

df2 = pd.read_csv(path + f2_name, header=f2_header, skipfooter=3)
df2['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

df3 = pd.read_csv(path + f3_name, header=f3_header, skipfooter=3)
df3['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['EPOCH_yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ'], format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')


i1, i2, i3 = 1, 1, 1
energies1 = [27, 40, 66, 108, 181, 310, 517]
energies2 = list(reversed(list(np.array([6, 7, 9, 13, 18, 27, 41, 65, 103, 164, 264, 426, 689, 1113])*1e-3)))
energies3 = list(reversed([0.137, 0.2, 0.29, 0.43, 0.64, 0.92, 1.34, 1.95, 2.85, 4.16, 6.08, 6.87, 12.97, 18.9, 27]))

#fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(10,10))
while i1 < 8 :
    ax[5].plot(df1.iloc[:, 0], df1.iloc[:, i1], c=cm.rainbow([50*i1]))
    ax[5].vlines(arrival_time(energies1[i1-1]), 0,0.3, color=cm.rainbow([50*i1]), label = str(energies1[i1-1]) + ' keV')
    ax[5].set_xlim(df3.iloc[0, 0], df3.iloc[-1, 0])
    ax[5].set_yscale("log")
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    i1 += 1

while i2 < 15 :
    ax[3].plot(df2.iloc[:, 0], df2.iloc[:, i2], c=cm.rainbow([20*i2]), label = str(round(energies2[i2-1]*1e3)) + ' eV')
    ax[3].vlines(arrival_time(energies2[i2-1]), 0,4e8, color=cm.rainbow([20*i2]))
    ax[3].set_xlim(df3.iloc[0, 0], df3.iloc[-1, 0])
    ax[3].set_yscale("log")
    i2 += 1

while i3 < 15 :
    ax[4].plot(df3.iloc[:, 0], df3.iloc[:, i3], c=cm.rainbow([20*i3]), label = str(round(energies3[i3-1]*1e3)) + ' eV')
    ax[4].vlines(arrival_time(energies3[i3-1]), 0,1e5, color=cm.rainbow([20*i3]))
    ax[4].set_xlim(df3.iloc[0, 0], df3.iloc[-1, 0])
    ax[4].set_yscale("log")
    i3 += 1

fig.tight_layout()

# bigger aspect ratio means shorter plot (and viceversa)
ax[3].set_aspect(0.00574) # 2002-04-25: 0.00646  
ax[4].set_aspect(0.004899) # 2002-04-25: 0.00684
ax[5].set_aspect(0.006865) # 2002-04-25: 0.01415

ax[4].set_ylim(None, 8e4)
ax[3].set_ylim(top=3e8)
ax[5].set_ylim(top=0.2)
ax[3].legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize = 11)
ax[4].legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize = 11)
ax[5].legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize = 11)
ax[5].set_xlabel('UT', fontsize = 20)
ax[1].set_ylabel('Frequency [kHz]', fontsize = 20)
ax[4].set_ylabel('Eletrons $cm^{-2} ster^{-1} s^{-1} eV^{-1}$', fontsize = 20)
plt.show()

plt.savefig(path + "Spec_Plot_2002_04_25", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: You will get more help with a _minimal_ self-contained example.  We don't have your data, and can't run your code, so its very hard to make suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, if I don't manage to get an answer here I'll try again with a minimal example :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `layout='compressed'`:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 4),
                        layout='compressed')

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.randn(10)

axs[0].plot(x, y)

im = axs[1].imshow(np.random.randn(10, 10), extent=[0, 10, 0, 10])
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axs[1], shrink=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, that's great! unfortunately when I try it it tells me __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'layout'. Do you know what the cause might be?

Comment: You are using an old Matplotlib?

Comment: Hadn't updated it in a while to be fair hahaha. I just updated it and the error is gone. It's still not aligning x axis for my code unfortunately

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I had forgotten to remove the tight layout and that was screwing with the compressed layout. Works a treat, thanks a lot!